Finding the Boyle temperature for Dieterici gas second equation of state
I'm faced with the problem of finding the Boyle temperature, $T_\text B$, for the gas obeying the following equation of state (sometimes called Dieterici gas second equation of state):
$$p=\frac{RT}{V_\text m-b}-\frac a{V_\text m^{5/3}}. \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
Boyle temperature is defined as a temperature for which the second virial coefficient becomes zero. So I need to present the equation of state of this gas in the form of a virial expansion. In order to do so I rewrote \eqref{eq1} as follows:
$$p=\frac{RT}{V_\text m\left(1-\frac b{V_\text m}\right)}-\frac a{V_\text m^{5/3}}=\frac{RT}{V_\text m}\left(1-\frac b{V_\text m}\right)^{-1}-\frac a{V_\text m^{5/3}},$$
after factoring out $RT/V_\text m$ and using Taylor expansion $\left(1-\frac b{V_\text m}\right)^{-1}=1+\frac b{V_\text m}+\frac{b^2}{V_\text m^2}+...$ I've got
$$\begin{align*}p&=\frac{RT}{V_\text m}\left(\left(1-\frac b{V_\text m}\right)^{-1}-\frac a{RTV_\text m^{2/3}}\right)\\&=\frac{RT}{V_\text m}\left(-\frac a{RTV_\text m^{2/3}}+1+\frac b{V_\text m}+\frac{b^2}{V_\text m^2}+...\right)\\&=\frac{RT}{V_\text m}\left(1+\left(b-\frac{aV_\text m^{1/3}}{RT}\right)\frac1{V_\text m}+\frac{b^2}{V_\text m^2}+...\right).\tag{2}\label{eq2}\end{align*}$$
Everything would be fine if the second virial cofficient in \eqref{eq2} did not contain molar volume, $V_\text m$, for virial coefficients as well as Boyle temperature do not depend on molar volume. Alternatively, I could find the expression for Boyle temperature simply by equating compressibility factor, $Z$, to $1$:
$$1=Z=\frac{pV_\text m}{RT_\text B}=\frac{V_\text m}{V_\text m-b}-\frac{aV_\text m}{RT_\text BV_\text m^{5/3}}\Leftrightarrow\frac{V_\text m}{V_\text m-b}-1=\frac a{RT_\text BV_\text m^{2/3}}\Leftrightarrow\frac b{V_\text m-b}=\frac a{RT_\text BV_\text m^{2/3}}\Rightarrow T_\text B=\frac{a(V_\text m-b)}{bRV_\text m^{2/3}}.$$
This result is also inadequate since again, Boyle temperature depends on molar volume. I think there is some mathematical trick to write this equation of state as a virial expansion with coefficients that depend only on temperature. I couldn't find any satisfactory information about it on the Internet or figure out how to express \eqref{eq1} for the appropriate virial expansion. Or maybe I misunderstand the definition of Boyle temperature? Any help to this problem will be appreciated!

You misunderstand math. One can have Taylor expansion of $1\over1+x$ at $x=0$ all right (and deduce many useful consequences from that). The same applies to $e^x$, $\sin x$, and a good many other functions... but not to $\sqrt[3]x$.

So there is no way to write down this equation of state as a virial expansion with coefficients depending only on temperature?

That's right.$!$
